# Delete partial dulicate rows - sql

Tags: sql-server

I have some troubles with deleting partial duplicate rows

The structure is like this:

```
+-----+--------+--+-----------+--+------+
| id  | userid |  | location  |  | week |
+-----+--------+--+-----------+--+------+
|   1 |    001 |  | amsterdam |  |   11 |
|   2 |    001 |  | amsterdam |  |   23 |
|   3 |    002 |  | berlin    |  |   28 |
|   4 |    002 |  | berlin    |  |   22 |
|   5 |    003 |  | paris     |  |   19 |
|   6 |    003 |  | paris     |  |   35 |
+-----+--------+--+-----------+--+------+
```

I only need to keep one row from each userid, it doesn't matter which week number it has.

Thanks,
Maxcim

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work across most databases:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id <> (SELECT MIN(id)
              FROM yourTable t
              WHERE t.userid = userid)
```

This query would delete from each `userid` group all records *except* for the record having the lowest `id` for that group.  I assume that `id` is a unique column.

Answer (score 0):

This method is tested, try it.
We are getting the number of rows occuring at each record, and then we are deleting only the ones with more than 1 row occruring... keeping the original one.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT UserID, Location,
RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, Location ORDER BY UserID, Location)
into #test1
FROM dbo.MyTbl

Delete MyTbl
From MyTbll
INNER JOIN #test1
ON #test1.UserID= MyTbl.UserID
WHERE RN > 1
if @@Error <> 0 GOTO Errlbl


Commit Transaction
RETURN

Errlbl:
    RollBack Transaction

GO
```